# Multiple criteria index matching

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have spent hours trying to work this out, found articles online but they don't appear to work.

I have an excel document with data on two tabs and want the below formula to show me the team people are on if the dates and userid match on both forms called "Raised Source" & "Sheet1"

```
{=INDEX(Sheet1!F:F,MATCH('Raised Source'!E:E&'Raised Source'!F:F,Sheet1!A:A&Sheet1!B:B,0))}
```

This throws out a #N/A error

Help!!!

Comment: So team names are on `Sheet1!F:F`? dates and userid are on A and B?

Comment: I've mocked up the data and it works for me... Perhaps it can't find a match, have you checked to be sure that a match does exist? Also, take care using array formulas on entire rows/columns, it slows down calculations considerably

Comment: If you give a clearer expectation of the expected outcome I would be more than happy to provide a full description of how Index and Match work together: a few examples of mine can be found in answers that I have provided before: [Index() Small() example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41549674/how-to-categorise-a-column-in-excel-based-on-another-column-that-contains-value/41565539#41565539) & [INDEX() to check 3 conditions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40805108/how-compare-3-columns-and-put-yes-or-no-in-another-column/40806443#40806443)

Comment: Thank you kindly for the replies - The raised source sheet shows me dates and userid's. I want to see what team the user was on at the date listed on the raised source sheet. Sheet2 has a date column, userid and team name. I hope this makes a bit more sense? Thanks

Comment: first check that both the dates columns are formatted identically just in case that could be throwing an error. As stated before, are you expecting a result (is the date and user id present on the same row in the data? / are you expecting it to be smart and find the next lowest date for that user if date not found etc.). As far as I can tell you have posted a working formula so I believe that the match just isn't there...

Comment: I am using this formula you posted in another question. =IF(IFERROR(INDEX($E:$F,MATCH(1,(A3=$E:$E)*(B3=$F:$F),0),3),FALSE),"OK","")    This just shows all blank cells. Literally spending 8 hours working on this formula, doh!

Comment: You're asking for column 3 in a 2 column range, Index only looks through the first range you specify and does not consider the rest of the workbook.

Comment: answer incoming with tutorial breakdown so give me a few minutes for the write up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly I assume that your data is in this format:

[image]
[image]

And that you are looking to perform the search using data from `'Raised Source'!` to search through `Sheet1!` and return the team from `Sheet1!` as well.

**The formula:**

The formula will need to be entered as an array (once copy and pasted while still in the formula bar hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>)

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Team,MATCH(1,(E1=TeamDate)*(F1=UserID),0)),"")`

I have used named ranges to make the formula neater these are:

```
Team      =Sheet1!$F$1:$F$6
TeamDate  =Sheet1!$A$1:$A$6
UserID    =Sheet1!$B$1:$B$6
```

Please note that when using an array formula on an entire column calculations slow down considerably so it is best to avoid that and define the exact range you are searching through or overshoot it by a sensible amount if you expect additions.

**The Logic:**

`=INDEX(array,row,[column])` - This formula will *'index'* the array you specify, you can tell it a row number and column number you want returned (for example `=INDEX(B3:C4,1,1)` will return the value in the first row and first column of `B3:C4` which is `B3`. We don't need to tell the formula a column if we just want the first column returned or if the data we are looking for results in is only 1 column wide.

This is where the formula comes in. We use the `MATCH(lookup_Value,Lookup_array,[match_type])` formula to tell us what position (or what row in this case) the value we are looking for occurs.

Normal use of `MATCH()` would be matching exact cell contents within a range but as we are using an array formula I played a little trick by using `MATCH(1,(E1=TeamDate)*(F1=UserID),0)`

So, I have told the formula to find `1` and tell me the position that it occurs. `1` is returned when both criteria match as with Excel formula, `TRUE` represents `1` and `FALSE` represents `0`. When this formula works through row by row, if both results match and return `TRUE` then the array will store `1*1` which is `1` and of course if either or both are `FALSE` then it will return `1*0`, `0*1` or `0*0` all of which result in `0`.

As the named ranges all start on the same row, the relative position (or how many times until a `1` appears) will always be the row number that you want the `INDEX()` formula to return.

`IFERROR(value,value_if_error)` - If no match is found, the formula will throw an error as it is unable to match `1` to the array that I have built. If this occurs I have told the formula that I would like it to return `,"")` instead which is a blank cell. You can update this to any text you would prefer, perhaps `,"Not Found")`?

*The other IF() in the formula from the other answer was specific to that question as they only wanted to know that there was a match rather than return something from that row.*

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I cant believe it - Best most detailed reply I have ever seen. I have now also got it working thanks to you helping. Really appreciate it. Thank you