# Index Match using multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using a function to fetch the data from amother sheet using 2 criteria on one sheet.

```
=INDEX('SHEET1'!J:J, MATCH(OFFSET(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()),,10) & L10, 'SHEET1'!G:G&'SHEET1'!H:H,0)
```

So basically I need to fetch the value from sheet1 ,column J  into my sheet 2 for each cell

-if the value in column A in sheet2 matches to the value in column G in sheet 1 and 
-if L10 value in sheet2 matches the value in column H in sheet 1.
When I ctrl+shift+enter ,it doesn't works.

Can someone help me with this formula please?

Comment: Could you provide some example data and an expected output please?

Comment: Also, I have a previous answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41634104/multiple-criteria-index-matching/41638516#41638516) that will help explain the INDEX MATCH formula in detail and may help you to close the gap yourself. Let me know if this helps and if it doesn't, please provide some example data so that I can play around with the formula to make sure that it works before I post an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Glitch_Doctor, I have attached the images, hope you get.

Comment: The image is not getting attached :(

Comment: I can try explaining.

Comment: There are various team in column A. There are two dates with three rounds. so Row 1 has date 1 and date 2. Date 1 has further 3 columns inside it as round 1, round 2 and round 3 in row 10.And so does date 2. now I have a sheet 2 which has 3 columns: team, round and score. I need to match the team and round and fetch the score from sheet 2.

Comment: Then it's all in the other answer - you just need to change the match to work as an array `MATCH(1,(criteria1)*(criteria2),0)`. I would just dump an answer in but I can't duplicate answers.  You have already given the conditions so fit them in the other formula. L10 will just need to be locked off with F4 so it doesn;t update from formula dragging like so: `$L$10`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple criteria index matching](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41634104/multiple-criteria-index-matching)

Comment: My pleasure, glad you got your solution.